# scipy sparse: obtain values present in both matrices

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have two `sparse` matrices that I want to compare element-wise:

```
from scipy import sparse as sp
t1 = sp.random(10, 10, 0.5)
t2 = sp.random(10, 10, 0.5)
```

In particular I would like to make a scatterplot for those elements present (i.e. non-zero) in both matrices, but so far the only way I could think of is to convert them to the dense format:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(t1.todense().flatten(),
         t2.todense().flatten(),
         'ko',
         alpha=0.1)
```

Which works terribly when the matrices are very large. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

[image]

Comment: As plotted you have a marker (a Line2D) for each element of the dense array (100). `t3=t1.multiply(t2)` will have nonzero values where both are also nonzero.  I can imagine using that using that information to select elements from both `t1` and `t2`, but haven't worked out the details.  I don't think there's anything off-the-shelf that will do this for you, since it's a rather specialized plot (not something everyone wants to do with sparse matrices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [256]: t1
Out[256]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 50 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [257]: t2
Out[257]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 50 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

When plotting `t1.todense().flatten()` you plot data points for all elements of `t1`, whether zero or not.  In this case 100 points.

One way to 'weed' out the zero elements is:

```
In [258]: t3 = t1.multiply(t2)
In [259]: t3
Out[259]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 28 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [260]: t11 = t3.astype(bool).multiply(t1)
In [261]: t21 = t3.astype(bool).multiply(t2)
In [262]: t11
Out[262]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 28 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

`t3` has nonzero values where both `t1` and `t2` are nonzero.  `t11` has the corresponding elements of `t1` (`t3` floats become boolean True and implicitly 1 in the multiply.)  Sparse `multiply` is relatively efficient (may be not as much as the corresponding dense multiply or even the sparse matrix multiply).

We could plot `t11.todense.ravel()` etc.  That would be the same, except for a concentration of values as (0.0, 0.0).  But the `data` attribute has the nonzero values, and the sparsity of `t11` and `t21` is the same, so we can just plot those - only 28 values in this case:

```
plt.plot(t11.data,
         t21.data,
         'ko',
         alpha=0.1);
```

There may be other ways of getting `t11` and `t21` matrices, but the basic idea still applies - get two matrices with the same sparsity, and plot just their `data` values.

[image: <code>t1</code>vs<code>t2</code>]

[image: <code>t11.data</code> vs <code>t21.data</code>]